# How change the Connection Arguments (after, before) in graphene-python (relay)?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django, graphql-python

Using:

- Django 3.x [ Django-Filters 2.2.0, graphene-django 2.8.0, graphql-relay 2.0.1 ]
- Vue 2.x [ Vue-Apollo ]

---

After applying some filters (iContains etc.) on my graphQL search i tried to change or manipulate the `connection_args` like `first`or `after`. I can fetch a Dictionary on my resolver like `{'first': 2, 'name__icontains': 'eagle'}` with values i put in the IDE. As you can see (Example 1 /def resolve_all_birds2) i use that already for a logic. But i do not understand where do manipulate the GraphQLArgument states of the `before`. `after` `first`. `last` function which comes with relay?

> **Example 1**

```
class ExtendedConnection(Connection):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    total_count = Int()
    edge_count = Int()

    def resolve_total_count(root, info, **kwargs):
        return root.length

    def resolve_edge_count(root, info, **kwargs):
        return len(root.edges)

class Birds2Node(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Birds
        filter_fields =  {
            'id':  ['exact', 'icontains'],
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith', 'iendswith'],
        }

        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
        connection_class = ExtendedConnection

    # --- CUSTOM FIELDS -->
    # pkey = _db primary key 
    pKey = Int()
    def resolve_pKey(parent, info):
        return parent.pk

    # qRank = Item Rank in Edge Array
    qRank = Int()
    def resolve_qRank(parent, info, **kwargs):
        return info.path[2]

class Birds2Query(ObjectType):
    birds2 = relay.Node.Field(Birds2Node)
    all_birds2 = DjangoFilterConnectionField(Birds2Node)


    def resolve_all_birds2(self, info, **kwargs):
        if 'name__icontains' in kwargs:
            nameIcon = kwargs['name__icontains']
            nameIconBool = bool(nameIcon.strip()) # if blanks turns False
            if nameIconBool == False: # has blanks         
                return Birds.objects.filter(name=None)
            pass

        if 'name__istartswith' in kwargs:
            nameIsta = kwargs['name__istartswith']
            nameIstaBool = bool(nameIsta.strip()) # if blanks turns False
            if nameIstaBool == False: # has blanks         
                return Birds.objects.filter(name=None)
            pass      

        return
```

---

For example, in my IDE i declare `allBirds2(first: 2, name_Icontains: "a")...` i can fetch these values with my resolver as a Dictionary via **kwargs`` or via args  `def resolve_all_birds2(self, info, first, name_icontains):` so far so good, i can manipulate my ModelQuery and it returned only 2 per Edge.

But Imagine i want to change `first: 2` to `first: 10` in my BackEnd? Can i update the Dictionary? The Documentation means yes, but it seems strict related to the ObjectTypes (Fields) you resolve. 
For Example i tried this...

> **Example 2**

```
def resolve_all_birds2(self, info, **kwargs):
     <...>            
    return {'first': '20', 'name__icontains': 'd' }
```

**Output IDE:** "message": "'dict' object has no attribute 'model'"

> **Example 3**

```
def resolve_all_birds2(self, info, first, **kwargs):
     <...>            
    return f'20, {first}!'
```

**Output IDE:** "message": "name 'first' is not defined",

---

> **Question**

Unfortunately i found only parameter manipulation on the modelquery in the graphene-python docs. 
So my Question is how can i manipulate - in my backend - the Values of the Fields `before`. `after` `first`. `last`, that relay offers and that are already useable in my IDE. Do i have to declare them extra in my DjangoObjectType or create a custom Node to manipulate and change the values after a user sends a request?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a middleware would probably allow changing the input values after the request is made and before running the query. Graphene has an example at: https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/execution/middleware/

However, it's not clear (to me) from the documentation which of the mentioned parameters would contain the `first` field you want to manipulate.

The middleware approach does not seem to be highly recommended, though, because this is an undesirable side effect: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/1285